# Updates to Dynamic Features

Tags: android, google-play, dynamic-feature

I'm introducing dynamic features in my Android app and want to know the scenario if I upload a new version to the store that contains updates in the dynamic feature module ONLY? Will all the users see that there is an update? Or will only the ones that have the dynamic feature installed see it?

Giving an example to make sure the question is clear. 
Let's say the app has dynamic feature D. User A has the app installed and the dynamic feature D installed as well. User B has the app installed WITHOUT dynamic feature D. If the app developer uploades an update to the store that only has updates in the dynamic feature part. Will user B see that there's an update in the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will upload a new .aab file for a new version of your app.
This is always the full application.

The Play Store decides what to deliver to the user via [delta updates](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html).
But there's no way for you as developer to only flag a single module for update.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty simple.All the users who have installed the app from playstore will see that a new update is available for download and it is there choice if they download it.

Comment: Your answer does not cover the important part of the question. I'm specifically talking about an update to a dynamic feature.