# Is it possible to publish update for only dynamic feature module?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am playing around with android app bundle with dynamic feature modules.
I have created 2-3 feature modules. Now I want separate release cycle for all these features and for base app.

So is it possible to publish only updated feature module and user devices get update for only these updated module?

Answer (score 3):

I was myself searching for the same possibility with the dynamic feature modules. It seems that currently we do not have the option of pushing the .aab for only a particular dynamic feature module. It is mandatory to upload a new .aab file with all the code to the play console. It is internally taken care by the way updates are delivered using an algorithm known as the [delta algorithm](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html) which only updates the modules to which an update has been pushed. Kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786906/updates-to-dynamic-features) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697121/can-we-publish-only-dynamic-feature-modules-when-there-is-a-code-change-in-featu) following links to get more insights.