# Can we publish only dynamic feature modules when there is a code change in feature rather than publishing entire app again?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-app-bundle, google-play-core

Suppose we have different feature modules in our project, and there is a code change in one of the on demand features. Now What I want to know is can we build .aab(android app bundle) or .apk for only that feature in which there is code change and upload it on playstore, rather than building entire app again and the uploading the .aab file. And only the updated feature gets downloaded in users phones rather than entire app again.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible.

To ensure full compatibility between the base module and the dynamic feature modules, the whole App Bundle with all its modules must be uploaded every time.

Note however that the users will only get a patched version of your app, they won't have to download the whole app again, only the difference between the version they have and the new version, hence if the  base module hasn't changed, the download will be very small for that APK.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism for a partial update.  You upload an apk with the whole app in it.

Comment: I believe the question is about App Bundles, not APKs.

Comment: @Pierre Same answer.  These work on a replacement basis, not a patch basis.  Which unless bandwidth is an issue is a far better process, it ensures you have a consistent install.

Comment: Play always serves patches for updates (when possible). It results in the same APK being installed since the patching happens before installation.